# Unable to access admin shares on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I cannot access the any network shares of a Windows 2008 R2 server from any other server or workstation on the domain. The error is always the same `Error code: 0x80070043 The network name cannot be found.`

Is there something that I can do to test the connectivity?

Comment: Network shares or admin shares? Can you ping the server by name? By IP? Can you access the server by \\ip.address? Also try disabling any Anti-Virus on the server to see if you have a better result.

Comment: Both types of shares. I am able to ping, and I've tried disabling antivirus, to no avail

Comment: is the windows firewall active?

disable all firewall profiles (start -> administrative tools -> windows firewall) and try it again.

Comment: Nope filewall is offline; the service is stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solution: uninstall symantec 11 for windows 2008 r2

Comment: I've seen symantec firewall do that. If you checked the symantec firewall logs, you'll notice it's blocking access to ntoskrnl.exe. You can create an exception for that in the firewall in symantec. That was the fix in my case anyway.